# Finite dimensional representation of semi-simple Lie algebras are hermitian?

Tags: representation-theory, semisimple-lie-algebras

In a quantum field theory book (Schwartz, Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model), I came across the statement that "all finite-dimensional representations of semisimple Lie algebras are hermitian".

I did not find any reference citing this result.

In addition, is it not $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$ a semisimple Lie algebra, with a finite-dimensional representation which is not Hermitian (or skew-Hermitian)?

E.g. I take the well-known representation

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}, 
Y=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix},
H=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Am I misunderstanding the statement? Sorry for the triviality of the question.

Thank you

Comment: What specifically do you mean by a Hermitian representation? The usual definition I know of is a "contravariant Hermitian form", which is an inner product on $V$, together with an automorphism $\omega$ of the Lie algebra such that $\langle xv, u \rangle = \langle v, \omega(x) u \rangle$ for all $u, v \in V$ and $x \in \mathfrak{g}$. So with this definition you would also need to specify the automorphism. (Usually it is the _Chevalley automorphism_, switching $X$ and $Y$ and possibly negating $H$.)

Comment: I guess that the statement refers to a representation $R: \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow V$ on a Hilbert complex space $V$, with the property that $\langle R(g)^{\dagger}y,x\rangle =\langle y,R(g)x\rangle$ for every $g \in \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: And $R(g)=R^{\dagger}(g)$... Sorry, I left out this piece from the comment.

Comment: If $R \colon \mathfrak{g} \to V$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_2$, then $R(X)$ and $R(Y)$ must be nilpotent. The only nilpotent Hermitian operator is the zero operator, so the only representation in which $R(X) = R(X)^{\dagger}$ is the zero representation. So I doubt this is what the book means: I would probably look around for the actual definition.

Comment: The requirement in quantum field theory is that the associated Lie Group representation shall be unitary (i.e. $U^{-1}(g)=U^{\dagger}(g)$, with $g$ element of the group). From this comes the requirement at algebra level. Apart from scrappy physicists' notations, this is the idea.